# Suppose $\int_{R^n} f(x,y) \phi_k dx =0$, then $f(x,y) = 0 a.e$ (proof, 2 questions regarding)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

Original source: (http://www.math.mcgill.ca/toth/hw3solutions.pdf) (page 2)

1. Is there a typo in the first part? Because I thnk this person was trying to say that $\phi_j$ is orthogonal to $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \overline{f(x,y)}\phi_k(x) dx $  for **each j** and then therefore $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \overline{f(x,y)}\phi_k(x) dx  =0$ for each $k$ (Because the equation imply that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \overline{f(x,y)}\phi_k(x) dx$ is in the basis of $(\phi_k)$, and it was true for each $k$, so this must be the $0$ vector)

2.Why is $m(M_k) = 1$? (Is this the set where $f(x,y)\phi_k$ is defined?

Comment: 1) I don't think that's a typo. The rationale is essentially what you said, but they didn't mention the "for all $j$" as this is implied. But the conclusion is indeed "for every $k$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \overline{f(x,y)}\phi_k(x)dx=0$ a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$."
2) It seems like this source is using $m(M_k)=1$ to mean $M_k$ has full measure, i.e. $m(M_k^C)=0$. Which does not make sense if this is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. However you should agree that if $M_k$ has full measure then $\cap_{k \geq 1} M_k$ has full measure as well, which is the conclusion they ultimately make.

Comment: @kccu, I am going to be the odd-one and just ask the obvious, what *is* $M_k$ precisely? My guess is as good as what I have in the parentheses.

Comment: $f(x,y)\phi_k(x)$ is defined everywhere. The set $M_k$ comes from the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \overline{f(x,y)}\phi_k(x)dx=0$ a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What does "a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$" mean? It means the equality holds for all points except those in a set of measure zero. That is, there exists a set $M_k$ where the equality holds, and $m(M_k^C)=0$.

Comment: @kccu, so the $1$ in $m(M_k) = 1$ is completely up to them and the emphasis is on $m(M_k^c) =0 $? I understand the interaction thing.

Comment: @Hawk I'm not sure what you mean by "completely up to them." I'm not aware if this source has established particular conventions regarding notation for sets of full measure (which would be incredibly misleading as $m(E)=1$ would mean two different things). I believe the intended meaning was $m(M_k^C)=0$, which leads to a correct proof.

Comment: @kccu, I meant it just has to be a nonzero (positive) measure right?

Comment: @Hawk, no that won't suffice. The set has to be of full measure to get the almost-everywhere result. (You can come up with a countable collection of sets of measure 1 whose intersection is empty - for the intersection result to hold, the sets need to be of full measure.)

Comment: @kccu, so you are saying if I say $m(M_k) = 3$ for example, that's not going to work? You said that it wouldn't make sense if $m$ was the Lebesgue measure on$\Bbb R^n$ because…?

Comment: @Hawk Right because imagine $M_1=[0,1]^n$, $M_2=[1,2]^n$, $M_3=[2,3]^n$, ... these all have measure 1 but their intersection has measure 0. When I said "it wouldn't make sense if $m$ was Lebesgue measure" I meant that $m(M_k^C)=0$ is not the same thing as $m(M_k)=1$ for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @kccu, from what I am understanding, you pointed out that if $M_k$ was a square, then it is not true $m(M_k^C) = 0$ if $m - Leb$ and its intersection is not $1$ as well. But $M_k$ is the set of all $y$ such that the integral is $0$. So the interaction and everything should still follow. I am still not understanding why the measure must be $1$ for this to work.

Comment: *$M_k$ was a sequence of disjoint sets with measure $1$

Comment: Because ultimately you need to conclude that $f(x,y)=0$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. The "interaction" (if by that you mean "intersection") will not work if the $M_k$ do not have full measure; and even if it did, they must have full measure in order for you to conclude that $f(x,y)=0$ holds for almost every $(x,y)$. ("Almost every" = "on a set of full measure" = "on a set whose compliment has measure 0")

Comment: Sorry autocorrect change my words sometimes. I don't see how the definition of full measure (a set whose complement has measure $0$) must imply $M_k$ has measure $1$. I don't see why $M_k$can't have measure $3,4, 5$.

Comment: That's my point - $m(M_k)=0$ does _not_ imply $M_k$ has measure 1. Hence the flaw in this proof. The proof will not work if $M_k$ has measure 1 or finite measure, or even infinite measure (because infinite measure does not imply the compliment has measure zero). What _is_ necessary is that $m(M_k^C)=0$.

Comment: @kccu, I think you meant to say "$m(M_k^C) =0$ does not imply $m(M_k) =1$" (because that was originally my question in my OP). So what exactly should be the correction to make this work? I can ask it in a different question if you would like.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write the complement. I already said what the correction is: say $m(M_k^C)=0$, then $m\left(\left(\bigcap_{k \geq 1} M_k\right)^C\right) =0$.

Comment: If you have further questions about this, I would recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @kccu, not much, but basically to complete what you wrote (and what I thought). We want to say the set $M_k^c = \{ \int_\Bbb R^n f(x,y)\phi_k dx = 0 a.e \}^c $ to have measure $0$, and since this is true for each $k$, the intersection is $0$ and we get $f = 0$ a.e.